# Change wrap width in a text file using Vim

Tags: text, formatting, editor, vim

I want to format srt subtitle text files to avoid wrapping problems on my media player.

I need to set a line wrap width to a number of characters e.g. 43

I can do this with Editplus, its a built in function and works well.  The reason I want to do it in Vim, firstly Editplus is only available on the PC and the secondly Vim is badass.

I have found the following solution on the net..

> :set tw=43
> gggqG

It does work, but not exactly how I want it.

E.g.

I have this text:

> 557
> 00:47:39,487 --> 00:47:42,453
> I will have to complete some procedures,
> and I asked you to check out what they are for me

after I format it, I get:

> 557 00:47:39,487 --> 00:47:42,453 I will
> have to complete some procedures, and I
> asked you to check out what they are for
> me

It seems to ignore line breaks/CRs.  As you can see the "I will" has been added to the first line.

How do I get it to not ignore line breaks?

EDIT: apoligies about the formatting, first time using stackoverflow!

Comment: it looks like it's formatting by paragraph (weird considering your commands are correct).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the whitespace option of `formatoptions` and make the lines you want to wrap end in whitespace.

```
:set tw=43
:set fo+=w
:g/^\a/s/$/ /
gggqG
```

The third line adds a space on the end of any line starting with a letter and `fo+=w` stops `gq` from joining lines that don't end in spaces.

See:

```
:help fo-table
:help 'formatoptions'
:help gq
:help :g
```

**Edit in response to comments**

```
:g/^\a/s/$/ /
```

This translates to:

```
:g/   " Search the file
^\a   " For lines starting (^) with an alphabetic character (\a - equivalent to [A-Za-z])
/     " Then on each line that the regexp matches (i.e. each line starting with an alphabetic character)
s/    " Substitute...
$     " The end of line (zero-width match at the end of the line)
/ /   " With a space (slashes are delimiters)
```

The global (`:g`) command will only operate on the current file, but the `textwidth` and `formatoptions` lines will last for the whole session.  If you want those options to only be used on the current buffer, use `:setlocal` instead:

```
:setlocal tw=43
:setlocal fo+=w
:help :setlocal
```

Comment: Great! This now imitates the behaviour of Editplus.  However there are aspects of erichui's answer which works even better.  Because this solution still accounts for line breaks, if a word is past 43 char mark, it is pushed onto the line below, but it will still maintain the original line break so therefore one line could potentially only have one word on it followed by another line, just looks strange.  But thats just being fussy now! Thanks Al :)

Comment: And what exactly does ":g/^\a/s/$/ /" mean? Also once I have run that command, Vim seems to remember it for any document I open in that session, how do reset it back to default without reopening Vim?

Comment: @Jon: I've added an explanation of :g///.  Also an explanation of how to make the settings buffer local.  I'm not sure I understand the comment about a line with one word on it: as far as I understand it, if all the lines end in space, gq should sort them out.  Perhaps you could give an example?

Answer (score 2):

If the only lines you want to wrap are the ones that start with text (ignore the ones that start with numbers) you can use the following.

```
:g/^[a-zA-Z]/normal gqq
```

This will run [p00ya's command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318470/change-wrap-width-in-a-text-file-using-vim/1318513#1318513) on each text line in the file.

Answer (score 1):

With the following text (i.e. only 3 lines):

```
557
00:47:39,487 --> 00:47:42,453
I will have to complete some procedures, and I asked you to check out what they are for me
```

Use `gqq` (format current line) on the 3rd line after setting `tw`.  Formatting by paragraph will not work since vim will treat all 3 lines as part of the same paragraph (paragraphs only end with a blank line).

Comment: This unfortunately won't be suitable as a single text file will be made up of hundreds of 'blocks'.  From the example that is the 577th! So editing a paragraph will be time consuming.  I am looking for a way to automate the process for the whole file, like what gggqG does.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly robust (or elegant), if you can assume that the subtitle lines do not begin with numbers, you can configure Vim to treat them as comments.

```
:set comments=:0,:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9
gggqG
```

Lines starting with 0-9 will be treated as comments and won't be merged together with the text.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see exactly what the issue is due to the formatting of your post, but you might want to checkout the 'formatoptions' setting in vim's help, specifically :he fo-table which contains a bunch of customization flags.

[This link](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_wrap_without_line_breaks) might be useful.